# « Je ne comprends pas son raisonnement/sa logique/l’idée qu’elle a bien pu se faire de ma demande? »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quand je suis arrivée à la fenêtre de la commande à l’auto pour récupérer ma commande, j’ai reçu une crème glacée complètement liquide et le gobelet était très collant. J’ai donc demandé à la commise de m’en redonner un autre. Elle revient quelques minutes plus tard avec un nouveau gobelet mais avec la même crème « liquide » et me dit « tiens, j’ai changé le gobelet ». Et moi de me dire « Je n’arrive pas à la comprendre/à comprendre son raisonnement/sa logique/l’idée qu’elle a bien pu se faire de ma demande »

D’autres termes à proposer ?

Edit

Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a bien pu raisonner/pu raisonner ainsi.

Je n’arrive pas à la saisir.

Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a pu mal interpréter ma demande.

Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a pu prendre ma demande dans ce sens.

Je n’arrive pas à saisir comment son cerveau a bien pu traiter ma demande pour en arriver à ce malentendu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a bien pu raisonner/pu raisonner ainsi.

L'idée  qu'une employée habituée à servir de la nourriture doit raisonner pour déterminer qu'une crème glacée ne se sert pas fondue n'est pas du tout appropriée ; personne ne raisonne pour déterminer ce genre de chose : on  voit automatiquement et immédiatement si la chose donnée a l'aspect qui convient ou non.

> Je n’arrive pas à la saisir.

Cette remarque n'est pas appropriée non plus. On pourrait s'interroger sur l'attitude de la serveuse et se demander si peut-être elle n'aurait pas agit de façon hostile, la raison de cela étant encore indéterminée,  mais alors on ne se pose pas de question aussi profonde. « Saisir quelqu'un » tend à concerner les motivations plus profondes d'une personne.

> Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a pu mal interpréter ma demande.

Cette troisième remarque est assez appropriée : le comportement de la serveuse peut être perçu comme étant bizarre et on peut se demander ce qui aurait pu être inexact dans la réclamation ou comment les mots de cette réclamation auraient pu être compris à tort.

> Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a pu prendre ma demande dans ce sens.

Comme variante de la remarque précédente celle-ci est aussi acceptable.

> Je n’arrive pas à saisir comment son cerveau a bien pu traiter ma demande pour en arriver à ce malentendu.

Cette dernière remarque est problématique, d'une façon similaire aux trois premières. On va chercher trop loin en impliquant le cerveau ou on dit des choses trop évidentes en cela que l'on sait très bien  que c'est dans le cerveau que ça se passe. Si l'on veut référer à une entité qui caractérise une personne dans ce contexte, on utilise plutôt un terme habituel et  restreint de façon appropriée : « esprit » ou « tête ». Aussi, le terme « traiter », qui sera compris néanmoins, est un terme très technique, un terme de spécialiste du cerveau, si ce n'est pas qu'un terme utilisé par analogie avec l'informatique.

- Je n’arrive pas à saisir comment dans [sa tête / son esprit ] ma demande a pu être interprétée pour mener à un tel malentendu. (*une possibilité de reformulation*)

*Autres remarques*

- Qu'est-ce qui a bien pu lui passer par la tête ? Je veux une crème glacée normale…
- Elle n'a pas compris ce qui n'allait pas.
- C'est pourtant évident, personne ne veut de crèmes glacées fondues.

*Plus compréhensif, bien que pas le sujet de la question*

- J'aurais dû lui dire précisément ce qui n'allait pas et que je voulais un autre pot avec de la crème glacée solide.
- Elle a dû s'imaginer que j'étais un cas spécial, quelqu'un qui attend que ses glaces fondent pour les manger.

Answer (score 0):

De toutes les phrases que tu as suggérées, je dirais tout simplement :

- Je n'arrive pas à saisir.
- Je n'arrive pas à saisir ce qui s'est passé.  À quoi pense-t-elle ?

D'autres suggestions :

- J'hallucine.
- Je ne comprends pas comment elle a pu mal interpréter la demande.
- Je n'arrive pas à croire ; qu'est-ce qu'elle a ?
- Je ne comprends pas ce qui lui est arrivé pour trouver une telle solution / pour trouver une solution comme ça.
- Je ne comprends pas, elle n'a rien [pigé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Piger).
- Je ne comprends pas ce qu'elle n'a pas compris/pigé.

Dans un registre un peu moins poli :

- Mon œil.

Ou la chute littéraire :

- Je n'y vois goutte.

Comment: « Mon œil » est l'expression du fait que l'on pense que quelqu'un prétend certaines choses dont il/elle ne croit pas un mot ; s'il y a  bien un changement de registre, il y a surtout un changement de sens ; ça ne correspond pas. « Je n'y vois goutte » ne convient pas du tout : ce n'est pas utilisé figurativement.

Comment: @LPH Oui, et malheureusement je dirais que la commise a bien pu comprendre la demande mais a fait le minimum pour résoudre le problème.  Dans ce cas, je ferais le geste de *mon œil* en racontant cette histoire.

Comment: ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/oeil)) Mon oeil ! (pop., exclam. iron. d'incrédulité). (On peut faire le geste en même temps que l'on dit ça ou ne pas faire de geste.)

Answer (score 0):

Ce qui correspond le mieux à ton état d'esprit est:

> Je n’arrive pas à comprendre comment elle a pu prendre ma demande dans ce sens.

et la réponse à cette question est:

[...] *j’ai reçu **une** crème glacée complètement liquide et **le** gobelet était très collant. J’ai donc demandé à la commise de m’en redonner **un** autre.*

Tu as donc demandé **un** autre gobelet en précisant que celui que tu avais reçu était très collant. L'employée a correctement satisfait à cette demande en le remplaçant par un gobelet qui ne collait pas aux doigts.

Pour exprimer de manière non ambiguë ce que tu souhaitais, il aurait fallu que tu demandes qu'elle t'en redonne **une** autre (→ une autre crème glacée).